# Android DataBinding "??" notation and parametrized string from resources. How to avoid 'null' text?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-databinding

I have some `TextView`'s in my App that is compounded by a key from `strings.xml` resource file and a parameter that is passed dynamically. I use Android Data Binding where the '??' notation means it should replace nulls with blank strings, as example bellow shows. 
But when the parameter value is null until the `TextView` is full loaded with data we see something like "null min" when I like it to be: " min".

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_runtime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:text="@{@string/min(vm.runtime) ?? ``}"
    tools:text="120 min" />
```

in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="min">
    <xliff:g id="min">%d</xliff:g>
    min
</string>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `vm.runtime` may be null, but that is possibly a valid parameter to a string format, so it is considered valid and the `??` won't ever be evaluated.

One expression you can use is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_runtime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:text="@{vm.runtime == null ? `` : @string/min(vm.runtime)}"
    tools:text="120 min" />
```

If you want it to have the `min` instead of an empty string, you can format the string twice.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_runtime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:text="@{@string/min(@string/quantity(vm.runtime) ?? ``)}"
    tools:text="120 min" />
```

And your min is defined like this:

```
<string name="min">
    <xliff:g id="min">%s</xliff:g>
    min
</string>
```

And the quantity string would be simply:

```
<string name="quantity">%d</string>
```

I think this should format properly in all languages, though I would recommend using plurals instead of string for min if you plan to localize.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see it was too simply. Meanwhile, was trying a super workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418764/android-databinding-can-i-pass-constructor-parameter-to-my-data-variable

Comment: Actually that `` doesn't work...Could you send a valid solution to write empty string on Data Binding? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using integer placeholder in your strings xliff:

```
<xliff:g id="min">%d</xliff:g>
```

and passing there an empty string. Change your strings xliff to use string placeholder:

```
<xliff:g id="min">%s</xliff:g>
```

And convert vm.runtime to string.