# Android DataBinding: can I pass constructor parameter to my data variable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have a `MovieViewModel` class that is used as variable in my layout file.

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="udacity.nanodegree.android.p2.model.comum.MovieViewModel"/>;

</data>
```

According with [Android Data Binding docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html):

> A special variable named context is generated for use in binding
>   expressions as needed. The value for context is the Context from the
>   root View's getContext(). The context variable will be overridden by
>   an explicit variable declaration with that name.

I need to pass this special variable `context` to my class preferably by the constructor from layout file:

```
public class MovieViewModel {
    private Context context;

    public MovieViewModel(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }    
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

---

If not possible, I would like to pass it to my attributes, like:

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_release"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="@{vm.releaseDateFormated(context) ?? ``}"
                    tools:text="0000"/>
```

To use context in `MovieViewModel` as below:

```
public String getReleaseDateFormated (Context context){
    return releaseDate == null? null: context.getString(R.string.dateToYear, releaseDate);
```

According with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35001471/4785114) I could do that, but I tried and received the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method releaseDateFormated(android.content.Context) in class udacity.nanodegree.android.p2.model.comum.MovieViewModel
file:C:\Users\alexandre\Udacity\Nanodegrees\AndroidDevelopment\P2-PopularMovies\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_detail.xml
loc:74:40 - 74:70
****\ data binding error ****
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Is there a way to do that?

The data binding framework is not creating an instance of `MovieViewModel`. Hence, constructor parameters are your job, when *you* create the instance of `MovieViewModel`.

> I tried and received the error

Your error is not coming from the code in your question. The error refers to `releaseDateFormated()`.

Comment: I understand what you said, you are right about constructor. But the error says it doesn't found the method (because of context parameter), isn't it? Sorry! Sorry! I made a mistake, I paste the error from another field. I will correct the question, but the error occurs in anyway.

Comment: @alexpfx: "But the error says it doesn't found the method (because of context parameter), isn't it?" -- well, do you have a method named `releaseDateFormated()` that takes a `Context` as a parameter?

Comment: yes :) I have several methods like that, but I didn't see the error was about another method.

Comment: @alexpfx: You may want to update your question to show your `releaseDateFormated()` method implementation.

Comment: @alexpfx: I do not see the implementation of `releaseDateFormated()` on your `MovieViewModel` class in your question.

Comment: yes, I got confused when editing the question. but now it's there!

Comment: @alexpfx: Rename it to `releaseDateFormated()`, or change your layout to reference `getReleaseDateFormated()`. This method is not a JavaBeans-style getter method, as those do not take a parameter. Hence, I do not think that the data binding framework will try to put `get` on the front of the method name.